# Appending a python dictionary From inside an if statement

Tags: python, dictionary, if-statement, input, append

I'm trying to write a recipe program in Python that accepts user input and appends it to an empty dictionary, but each time I run the code, the dictionary remains empty. Please, what's wrong and what can I do ?

```
def action():
    answer = input("What would you like to do :- \n"" c.) Create a new recipe \n ""d.) Read all meal recipes \n\n")
    global recipes
    recipes={}
    if answer == "d" :
        print(recipes.values())
    elif answer == "c":
          name =str(input("\nWhat is the name of the food recipe you would like to create ? :- \n"))
          ingredients= str(input('\nWhat are the ingredients required to prepare this meal :- \n'))
          method =str(input('\n How is the meal prepared :- \n'))
          recipes[name]=[name,ingredients,method]
          recipes[name]
action()
```

Comment: Every time you call the function you empty the dictionary with `recipes = {}`

Comment: `input()` always returns a string, you don't need to call `str()`

Comment: Iniitialize the dictionary outside the function, not inside the function.'

Comment: this works for me, i can't reproduce issue. BTW not clearly stated but you have to enter `c` as the answer to add to the dict.

Comment: one possible approach could be, store the dict data in a file and when you start your code you can read data from that file

Comment: @Barmar What do you mean initialize ?

Comment: The assignment `recipes = {}` initializes it to an empty dictionary. You should just do this once, before you ever call the function.

Comment: @Barmar Ohhh . Should I initialize before or after defining the function?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
def action():
    global recipes
    recipes ={}
    while True:
        answer = input("What would you like to do :-\n"
                       "a.) Read a meal recipe\n"
                       "b.) Add to a recipe\n"
                       "c.) Create a new recipe\n"
                       "d.) Read all meal recipes\n"
                       "e.) Quit\n\n")

        if answer == "d" :
            print(recipes.values())
        elif answer == "c":
            name =str(input("\nWhat is the name of the food recipe you would like to create ? :- \n"))
            ingredients= str(input("\nWhat are the ingredients required to prepare this meal :- \n"))
            method =str(input('\nHow is the meal prepared :- \n'))
            recipes[name]=[name,ingredients,method]
            print(recipes[name])
        elif answer == "e":
            break
action()
```